# Blender only exporting moving frames

Tags: export

The animation contains a couple hundred frames with the armature not moving but the character has active shapekeys to make it blink, and the rest of the frames are the armature moving. I exported it as an FBX file and when I imported it back into blender to test it, It had only exported the frames in which the armature was moving. These are my export settings:

[image]

Comment: Does this apply here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262017/the-shape-keys-disappear-when-exporting-with-modifiers